# Create combination of all variables within a group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
group    x    y
a        1    2
a        3    1
b        1    3
c        1    1
c        2    3
```

I want to be able to generate all combinations of the x and y columns within a group, like so

```
group    xy
a        1-2
a        1-1
a        3-2
a        3-1
b        1-3
c        1-1
c        1-3
c        2-1
c        2-3
```

I've tried using the following code, but it seems as though the `group_by` function is not working as expected

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
combn <- df %>%
group_by(group) %>%
expand(x, y)
```

My current results are instead giving me every combination of all three columns

```
head(combn)

group    x    y
a        1    1
a        1    2
a        1    3
a        2    1
a        2    2
a        2    3
```

Dput:

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), x = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `crossing` from `purrr` to create combinations within a group and then `unnest` to create them as separate rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(group) %>%
        summarise(xy = list(crossing(x, y))) %>%
        tidyr::unnest(xy)
df1

#  group     a     b
#  <fct> <int> <int>
#1 a         1     2
#2 a         3     2
#3 a         1     1
#4 a         3     1
#5 b         1     3
#6 c         1     1
#7 c         2     1
#8 c         1     3
#9 c         2     3
```

If you want to combine the two columns, you could use `unite` :

```
tidyr::unite(df1, xy, a, b, sep = "-")

#   group xy   
#  <fct> <chr>
#1 a     1-2  
#2 a     3-2  
#3 a     1-1  
#4 a     3-1  
#5 b     1-3  
#6 c     1-1  
#7 c     2-1  
#8 c     1-3  
#9 c     2-3
```